# onserverclick function in my dnamic grid not accessing code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic grid in my .cs page and I have a div element in my aspx page that holds the ID of my grid.

I have added run at attribute in my div element to access it at code behind.

Now I have an onserverclick function in my dynamic grid which I have to access at my code behind. but, it does not get triggered. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

my code for the grid is as follows:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            html += "<tr class=\"GreyBorder\" id='tblFilesGrid_" + 
    dr["Id"].ToString() + "' pkid=\"" + dr["id"].ToString() + "\"  
       class=\"DataRow\">";
            html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" style=\"text-align:center 
        !important;\">" + Count + "</td>";
            html += "<td  align=\"center\" >" + dr["Name"] + "</td> ";



            html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><input 
      type=\"button\" runat=\"server"\  Id=\"btnView\" onserverclick=\"ShowDocument\" 
          runat=\"server\"/></td>";

            html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><img 
         title='remove' onclick='return DeleteRow(this)'  
            src='../../images/delete.png'></td>";



            html += "</tr>";
            Count++;


        }
    }
```

I somehow need to modify this line of code only

```
  html += "<td class=\"GreyBorder\" align='center'><input 
      type=\"button\" runat=\"server"\  Id=\"btnView\" onserverclick=\"ShowDocument\" 
          runat=\"server\"/></td>";
```

To access my function ShowDocument in my code behind. I have tried adding run at attribute but this function doesn't get triggered. plz, help.

Comment: its been a long time since I did any webforms development, however, this will be output in your HTML and not actually be a bound element.  Have you considered using an ajax call or does it have to be an onserver click button?

Comment: It has to be an onserverclick. I have this function defined in my code behind but it just does not get triggered

Comment: ok, next question, have you thought about creating this in a repeater on the aspx page it self or building it up as objects in the code rather than html strings?#

Comment: My grid has to be dynamic. I dont want to create it at aspx

Comment: If you want to access backend methods with `OnClick` or `OnServerClick` then you have to use @SimonPrice 's suggestion and use a Repeater or GridView. Or add Dynamic Controls. You cannot make it work by adding it to a string and writing it to the page.

Comment: I have no idea about repeater. Can you refer me any link that would explain?

Comment: @Unknown you could type "asp.net repeater" into google and get lots of suggestions. If you haven't already done that, then please do so. You'll find links like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/ . If you're trying to output a table though, a GridView might also be worth considering instead of a Repeater. Alternatively, you can trigger your server-side function as a WebMethod via an AJAX call. (That's just an idea. I don't know if that would work or not - it depends what the function actually does.)